# Helptags gives: E488: Trailing characters

Tags: vimrc, plugin-pathogen

I am relatively new to vim. I made my `.vimrc` file watching different tutorial in order to use vim mainly as a python IDE. I am using `pathogen` as plugin manager and I have recently installed `python-mode`. However when typying `:Helptags pymode` or `:Helptags NerdTree` I get:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

I suspect something is not right with my `.vimrc`..Here is what I am using:

```
 1 " Enable syntax highlight
 0 syntax on
 1 let python_highlight_all=1
 2 " Highlight your search
 3 set hlsearch
 4 set number relativenumber
 5 " Rebind <Leader> Key
 6 let mapleader = ","
 7 
 8 noremap <Leader>l :nohl<CR>
 9 
 10 " Quicksave command
 11 noremap <Leader>m :update<CR>
 12 
 13 " Quickquit command
 14 noremap <Leader>e :quit<CR> "Quit current wind
 15 noremap <Leader>E :qa!<CR> "Quit all wind
 16 nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
 17 
 18 
 19 execute pathogen#infect()
 20 call pathogen#helptags()
 21 
 22 filetype plugin indent on
 23 set number
 24 
 25 " Setting vim-colors-solarized
 26 " cd ~/.vim/bundle
 27 " git clone git://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git
 28 " It worked with this: cp .vim/bundle/solarized/vim-colors-solarized  /colors/solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
 29 let g:solarized_termcolors=256
 30 set t_Co=256
 31 set background=dark
 32 " Highlight useless white spaces
 33 autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
 34 au InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
 35 colorscheme solarized
 36 
 37 let g:pymode_python='python3'
 38 
 39 " Setting for NERDTree
 40 " cd ~/.vim/bundle
 41 " git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
 42 " toggle NERDtree
 43 map <Leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Can somebody help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It looks like you were trying to get help on plug-ins.

For that, you can simply call `:help`. Vim will look for help files in the plug-in directories, so something like `:help pymode` will work.

If you build the help tags for plug-ins (for instance, with the `:Helptags` command of pathogen, or `:helptags ALL` if you're simply using [packages](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages)), then the commands and bindings of plug-ins will be available through the help system as well.

For instance, you'll be able to use `:help :NERDTreeToggle` to get help on that specific command of the NERDTree plug-in.

---

You should call `:Helptags` on its own, without any additional arguments.

The point of `:Helptags` in vim-pathogen is that it will figure out which plugins have `doc/` directories that need help tags generated, and generate them for all of those.

From the [README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/README.markdown):

> Normally to generate documentation, Vim expects you to run `:helptags` on each directory with documentation (e.g., `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`). Provided with pathogen.vim is a `:Helptags` command that does this on every directory in your `'runtimepath'`.

---

Also consider just using [packages](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages) instead of pathogen, if you're using Vim 8 or later, or NeoVim. Packages are built-in to Vim and work very similarly to how pathogen does.

If you use native packages, then you can use [`:helptags ALL`](https://vimhelp.org/helphelp.txt.html#%3Ahelptags) to create tags for all your plug-ins (so you don't need pathogen's `:Helptags` either.)

Pathogen itself recommends using packages instead. From the [README](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/README.markdown):

> **For new users, I recommend using Vim's built-in package management instead.** [`:help packages`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, `:Helptags` alone actually does not give errors. But how can I get help on a particular plugin so?

Comment: Ah! Just use `:help` directly, such as `:help pymode` or on a specific command `:help :NERDTreeToggle`.

Comment: You can usually also use `:helptags ALL`, which is handy since I got rid of pathogen

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Added info on `:helptags ALL` and more recommendation towards using packages!